# VB NET 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProjectVB\Downloads\' because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: vb.net, pdf, watermark

I'm having trouble solving a problem about how to create a watermark in pdf using vb net.

Is there anyone here who can help solve my problem?

```vb
Dim document As Document = New Document()
' Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("C:\Users\IT-SMJ\Downloads\Documents\BUKU-ROLLY-YESPUTRA-VBNET.pdf")
Dim pdfReader As PdfReader = New PdfReader("C:\ProjectVB\Uploads\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Tcarifile.Text))
' Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(PdfReader, New FileStream("C:\Users\IT-SMJ\Downloads\Docs\BUKU-ROLLY-YESPUTRA-VBNET.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
Dim pdfStamper As PdfStamper = New PdfStamper(pdfReader, New FileStream("C:\ProjectVB\Uploads\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Tcarifile.Text), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
Dim img As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\Users\IT-SMJ\Downloads\watermaku.png")

img.SetAbsolutePosition(170, 70)

Dim waterMark As PdfContentByte

For pageIndex As Integer = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
    waterMark = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex)
    waterMark.AddImage(img)
Next

pdfStamper.FormFlattening = True
pdfStamper.Close()
```

Comment: In future, please look at the preview of your question and don't submit if it looks like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: In which line do you get the exception? I don't use iTextSharp, but the second parameter of `PdfStamper` is the output stream. It's the same as the one you used to create a `PdfReader` object. I think that's the issue here. Try to use another path.